# Primefaces PickList Limit number of transferred elements

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2, picklist

Salam,

I'm triying to implements a Primefaces PickList in my project, and i'm stuck with the max elements i have to transfer from source list to target :
in my case i want to trandfer max of 2 choices from a list of about 12 possible choices.

my selectChoice.xhtml looks like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <h1>Liste des cadres</h1>
</h:head>
    <h:body>
    <ui:composition template="../resources/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
        <p:messages for="update"/>
        <p:pickList id="pickList"  value="#{etudiantController.pickFiliere}" var="filiere" itemLabel="#{filiere.intitule}" itemValue="#{filiere}" />




        </h:form>
   </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

my managed bean is like this :

```
 public List<Filiere> getListFiliere() {
        listFiliere = filiereService.findAll();
        return listFiliere;
    }

    public void setListFiliere(List<Filiere> listFiliere) {
        this.listFiliere = listFiliere;
    }


    public DualListModel<Filiere> getPickFiliere() {
        if (pickFiliere == null) {
            pickFiliere = new DualListModel<Filiere>();
            pickFiliere.setSource(getListFiliere());
        }
        return pickFiliere;
    }

    public void setPickFiliere(DualListModel<Filiere> pickFiliere) {
        this.pickFiliere = pickFiliere;
    }

    public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(Object item : event.getItems()) {
            builder.append(((Filiere) item).getIntitule()).append("<br />");
        }

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        msg.setSummary("Items Transferred");
        msg.setDetail(builder.toString());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    } 

    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item Selected", event.getObject().toString()));
    }

    public void onUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item Unselected", event.getObject().toString()));
    }

    public void onReorder() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "List Reordered", null));
    }
```

How to tell my PickList to disable transfer of elements after doing 2 transfer.

thanx

///////////////////**********************////////////////////////////////////////
switched to SelectManyCheckbox like [melloware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502366/melloware) has suggested, because it seems more freindley for user to use checkbox, so my xhtml :

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="studentChoices" value="#{etudiantController.choixFLTmp}" layout="responsive" columns="3">
                <f:selectItems value="#{filiereController.allFilieres}" var="filiere" itemLabel="#{filiere.intitule}" itemValue="#{filiere}" />
                <f:validator validatorId="studentChoicesValidator" />
            </p:selectManyCheckbox>

          <p:message id="verifyMaxChoices" for="studentChoices"/>
```

i v created a validator based on [balusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) answers on this post : [How to validate the maximum amount of checked values of a selectManyCheckbox based on the current selection of a selectOneMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827675/how-to-validate-the-maximum-amount-of-checked-values-of-a-selectmanycheckbox-bas)

my Validator :

```
@FacesValidator("studentChoicesValidator")
public class StudentChoicesValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        List<Filiere> choixFLTmp = (List<Filiere>) value;
        if (choixFLTmp.size() > 2) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Vous ne pouvez cochez plus que deux(2) choix !", null));
        }        
    }    
}
```

For now the message does not apear in my xhtml, and user can do more than 2 check.

How am i supposed to fire the validation(in my mind i always thinked that it fires automatically)

thanx.

Comment: I am not sure Picklist is the right component for doing that from a UI perspective.  Maybe something like SelectManyCheckbox and try and limit their checks to 2 using some simple javascript/jquery.  Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Your idea seems interesting i will try it and post my progress

Comment: After several unsuccessful attempts, and errors I did not find the source, I opted for the use of a control button array that adds the selected element to an e-choice list.
It was easier to achieve and manage.
Sometimes it is necessary to know when to make strategic choices in deprive of the ergonomic dream which complex times things.
Thank you for all those who guided me.