# Cheking selected items in checkboxmenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm beginner in `jsf primefaces` and I'm using `checkboxmenu` option. How can I check if all the items are checked (All items are mandatory) ?

Comment: In a validator... Not something default built into this component (very uncommon request, effectively the first one I heard...  Sort of like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827675/how-to-validate-the-maximum-amount-of-checked-values-of-a-selectmanycheckbox-bas (it does not mattert the component type is a little different. Solution is very comparable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate the maximum amount of checked values of a selectManyCheckbox based on the current selection of a selectOneMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827675/how-to-validate-the-maximum-amount-of-checked-values-of-a-selectmanycheckbox-bas)

Comment: @Kukeltje I should pass all the items

Comment: ??? Sorry, I have no clue what you mean by this statement